# Do linked lists have a practical performance advantage in eager functional languages?

Tags: performance, haskell, linked-list, functional-programming, scheme

I'm aware that in lazy functional languages, linked lists take on generator-esque semantics, and that under an optimizing compiler, their overhead can be completely removed when they're not actually being used for storage.

But in eager functional languages, their use seems no less heavy, while optimizing them out seems more difficult. Is there a good performance reason that languages like Scheme use them over flat arrays as their primary sequence representation?

I'm aware of the obvious time complexity implications of using singly-linked lists; I'm more thinking about the in-practice performance consequences of using eager singly-linked lists as a primary sequence representation, compiler optimizations considered.

Comment: 1) Simplicity 2) Trivial O(1) prepend 3) Sharing

Comment: @Bergi Simplicity isn't really a "performance" advantage, but it is a reason. I'm not so sure I understand your sharing point, though. Assuming immutability, you can share flat arrays just as easily.

Comment: But you cannot share parts of arrays. Lists can share their tails.

Comment: @Bergi Does sharing happen at all in the context of an eager language? I guess you could do it manually.

Comment: @DavidYoung I didn't mean sharing of lazy computation, I did mean sharing of data structure components. I guess that's done in every language with immutable data structures, regardless whether lazy or eager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL; DR: No performance advantage!**

The first Lisp had `cons` (linked list cell) as only data structure and it used it for everything. Both Common Lisp and Scheme have vectors today, but for functional style it's not a good match. The linked list can have one recursive step add zero or more elements in front of an accumulator and in the end you have a list that was made with sharing between the iterations. The operation might do more than one recursion making several versions all sharing the tail. I would say sharing is the most important aspect of the linked list. If you make a minimax algorithm and store the state in a linked list you can change the state without having to copy the unchanged parts of the state.

Creator of C++ Bjarne Stroustrup mentions [in a talk](https://youtu.be/YQs6IC-vgmo) that the penalty of having the data structure scrambled and double the size like in a linked list is easily outperformed even if you insert in order and need to move half the elements in the data structure. Keep in mind these were doubly linked lists and mutation inserts, but he mentions that most of the time was following the pointers linearly, getting all the CPU cache misses, to find the correct spot and thus for every O(n) search in a sorted list a vector would be better.

If you have a program where you do many inserts on a list which is not in front then perhaps a tree is a better choice, which you can do in CL and Scheme with `cons`. In fact all of Chris Okasaki purly functional data structures can be implemented with `cons`. Most "mutable" structures in Haskell are implemented similar to it.

If you are suffering from performance problems in Scheme and after profiling you find out you should try to replace a linked list operation with an array one there is nothing standing in the way of that. In the end all algorithm choices have pros and cons. Hard computations are hard in any language.

Comment: It should be mentioned that C++ arrays/vectors are only so fast because they're by default _unboxed_ (memory-packed). That allows actually accessing the _elements_ without cache misses. But in dynamic languages (including limited OO dynamic typing) and also in Haskell et al., you can in general only have arrays as _arrays of pointers_, which means you'll still get cache misses if you need to look up the elements in an _O_ (_n_) search. Arrays will still be faster than linked lists, but not nearly but such a big factor as in C++.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I concur, but we now do have unboxed vectors in Haskell. These had to be defined using low level unsafe primitives, and only for unboxable types, but with those the performance should be closer to C++, at least.

Comment: @leftaroundabout No, the speed is primarily gained from removing memory dependencies; a vector of pointers will still be much faster than a linked list of values. Dereferencing memory is atrociously latent, but has not-atrocious throughput.

Comment: @Veedrac that only helps you when processing each element independently of the others, and also only when compiler and processor can reorder the instructions so well that the latency happens completely out-of-order. In practice, this often works decently nowadays, but still not as fast as when you avoid most of the latency-inducing cache misses entirely.

Comment: @leftaroundabout OoO will make this work even when the processing is not independent, as long as it's traversed roughly linearly; the loop will end up pipelined and the latency will be hidden. Obviously having contiguous data is even better, but it's comparatively less important.